# Typeorm and SQL Server RowVersion

Tags: sql-server, typeorm

What Typeorm decorators should you use with the SQL Server rowversion data type?

This Column decorator correctly creates the column in the database:

```
@Column({type: "rowversion", nullable: false })
```

However, when I save the entity, I get a runtime error because Typeorm is trying to insert a value into the database whereas the database should create the value itself:

> Error: Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column.

I've tried using the Typeorm @VersionColumn but typeorm still attempts to insert a value.

Comment: Use a `VirtualColumn` maybe? https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/83567f533482d0170c35e2f99e627962b8f99a08/docs/decorator-reference.md#virtualcolumn `@VirtualColumn({type: "rowversion", query: "YourColumnHere" })` or something like that

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I found a solution which used a transformer where the to function was an empty function (so nothing was written to the database) and the from function returned the value.

Comment: Add your answer as an answer then in case someone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which used a transformer where the to function was an empty function (so nothing was written to the database) and the from function returned the value.